# Merge a PR (not close) from git --squash

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

When I develop in a branch and merge it into master with:

```
git merge --no-ff $BRANCH
git push origin HEAD
```

It merges the PR in Github (the purple badge).

But if I want to merge it squashed:

```
git merge --squash $BRANCH
git add . && git commit -m "Merge branch '$BRANCH'"
git push origin HEAD
```

It remains open til I remove the branch:

```
git branch -D $BRANCH 
git push origin :$BRANCH
```

How can I merge a squashed branch and **merge (not close)** the PR in Github?

Here's an example repo: https://github.com/sospedra/better-pr-close

Comment: After `git merge --squash`, you need to run `git commit` to finish the merge.

Comment: Yes I do. I'll update the oc to avoid confusion

Comment: In some scenarios this works: once you've made the squash commit, you can do a force push to the PR branch first, wait for GitHub to update the PR with the new commit and then push to the integration branch (e.g. master). This only works if either you own the fork from which the pull request was made, or the person making the pull request has not unchecked the "allow edits from maintainers" when making the pull request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem.
I contacted the GitHub team by email and they tell me is not possible right now because they use the SHA's commit to link the merge commit with the PR.

Here's the full answer:

> The logic to automatically merge a Pull Request looks at the commit
>   SHA's present on the Pull Request.
>
> If all of the commit SHA's have been pushed to the base branch
>   already, we'll automatically mark it as merged.
>
> When you squash commits and push, the references to the original
>   commits are lost.
>
> This means that is isn't currently possible to mark a PR as merged if
>   the commits have been squashed and pushed from the command line.
>
> I can pass your request onto the team to consider for future
>   improvements.
>
> I can't promise if or when we'd add this but I'll for sure pass it
>   along!

They'll take the request into consideration. Hopefully will be added at some point.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the different mechanisms between `git merge` and `git merge --squash`.

Assume before merging the two branches, the commit history looks like:

```
…---A     master
     \
      B   alpha
```

**Situation 1:** If you are use `git merge --no-ff alpha`, the commit history will be:

```
…---A---C  master
     \ /
      B    alpha
```

After pushing the changes to github, PR knows commit `C` is the merged commit (since **commit `C` has two parents both on `master` branch and `alpha` branch**), so the PR will be closed.

**Situation 2:** If you are use `git merge --squash alpha`, the commit history will be:

```
…---A---C'   master
     \
      B      alpha
```

After pushing the changes to github, it’s hard for the PR to judge whether commit `C'` is the new changes for `master` branch or it’s the squash merged commit from `alpha` branch (**commit `C'` only has one parent**).

And for now, github only treat the situation1 for closing the PR since the `alpha` branch apparently merged into `master` branch. While for situation2,  since the commit `C'` only has one parent commit `A`, PR won’t be closed.